# How can I change the default image location for a Silverlight project in Visual Studio

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

Re: Visual Studio 2010 Silverlight 4.0 project.

When setting the source for an image element using the builder from the property sheet, it Visual Studio has a handy option to add an image file to the project and set it as the source for the control.

**The Problem:**
 Visual Studio wants to put those images in a folder called images off the root of my project, and will even create that folder if it doesn't exist. However, my project is structured so that the images should go in a different directory (assets\images). So I am always having to move them after using that builder.

**The Question:**
 Is there a way to configure the project or change the default in Visual Studio such that the builder puts newly imported images in a different directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think we can configure that. The best workaround for you would be to put a create a folder with all the images and add it to the project. From the Source property for Image control in the Properties window, you will able to select images from the "Choose image" dialog box.